# Will the Stack Exchange app be updated for the iPhone X's screen?

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

I was wondering if the app was going to be updated for the iPhone X screen.

Comment: Does it need to?

Comment: Since I got it, yes

Comment: Can you show how it is now? I am wondering what the exact problem is you are wanting to have fixed.

Comment: Well the screen is longer than the iPhone 6, so apps need to be updated. Actually it happened when Apple released the iPhone 5 and the screen was longer than the iPhone 4. I have no screenshot here but you can see that someone had the same problem with the Spotify's app : https://community.spotify.com/t5/iOS-iPhone-iPad/App-issues-on-iPhone-X/td-p/3013138